# Is it safe to buy hardwood floors from home renovation stores?

Tags: hardwood-floor, humidity

Some floor installers have warned me against buying hardwood floors from home renovation stores (box stores) because they claim that the wood is stored at sub-optimal humidity for months prior to sale which damages it.

Other installers I've talked to say that buying from these stores is fine, so long as I let the hardwood soak in the humidity of the house where it will be installed prior to installation.

Who is right?

Comment: Are we talking actual hardwood like tongue and groove, or that Pergo s***?   The problem with manufactured "hardwood" floors is it's bleepin rubbish, not that it's been stored wrong.

Comment: You should let your hardwood climitize no matter where you purchase it and monitor with a moisture meter. If the wood is not checked from drying two fast and the moisture content is correct I don't think anyone will be able to tell after the floor is finished or in 5, 10 years.

Comment: @Harper As far as I can tell, I am talking about actual hardwood: https://www.renodepot.com/en/hardwood-flooring-71415037

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old, and it's probably too late for the OP, however...

If you're talking real wood floors, and it appears that you are, it doesn't matter *where* you buy the flooring from - it should be stored inside your house for a couple of weeks to let it acclimatize to *your* indoor humidity before installing it.

Unless the wood was stored outdoors for *long* periods of time (a year or more) with zero weather protection, it's highly unlikely to actually be damaged (at least by the weather). It will, though, likely absorb a fair bit of moisture.

If it was purchased from a retailer that keeps all their lumber indoors in a climate controlled storage area, a few weeks will probably do it. If they kept it outdoors and the outdoor humidity over the last few weeks/months is significantly different than your indoor humidity, then you'll probably want to let it acclimatize longer. For example, in the Midwest USA, summers tend to be *very* humid and the wood will absorb a lot of that humidity. It will take a longer time to dry out once it's brought into the air conditioned house than if you purchased the wood in the winter/early spring. On the other hand, if you're buying wood in mid-winter, it could, possibly be *very* dry and your indoor humidity could be higher, thus the wood actually needs to absorb a bit of moisture before it's installed.

One of the advantages of a big-box store is that they tend to do a higher volume, so things usually *don't* sit on the shelf for long periods of time. If you're purchasing something a bit unusual from a flooring specialist (especially if you're getting a good deal on it), it may have been sitting in their warehouse for *months* absorbing moisture, and they're giving you a deal to get it off their shelf.

If you're installing the floor yourself, getting a moisture meter would probably be a good investment. If you're having it installed, ask the flooring guys to get a moisture reading as soon as it's delivered, and ask what level they want it to be at before they install it. They'll probably give you an estimate of how long it'll take to get there once it's been delivered.